# How to collect javadoc jars into a zip file

Tags: gradle

For a multi-project Gradle project, foo, bar and baz. I'm trying to create a task which creates a zip file with both libraries and javadoc, i.e. foo.jar, AND foo-javadoc.jar..

```
./build.gradle
./settings.gradle
./foo/build.gradle
./bar/build.gradle
./baz/build.gradle
```

settings.gradle

```
include ":foo"
include ":bar"
include ":baz"
```

Top level build

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    task generateJavadoc (type : Javadoc) {
        source = sourceSets.main.allJava  
        classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
        failOnError = false             
    }
    task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: generateJavadoc) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from generateJavadoc.destinationDir                     
    }   
    artifacts {
        archives javadocJar     
    }

}

task buildZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: build) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from (project(':foo').configurations.runtime) {
        into 'jars'
    }
    from (project (':foo').configurations.archives.all) {
        into 'jars'
    }
}
```

When I invoke this with `gradle clean buildZip` a zip file is created, but without the any -javadoc JARs I was expecting... The JavaDoc jars are generated into the project build directories, e.g. foo/build/lib/foo-javadoc.jar I've tried multiple combinations of from `project (':foo').artifacts` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the following. Note `javadocJar` is the name of the task defined in the `allprojects` block

```
from (rootProject.allprojects.javadocJar.outputs) {
    into 'javadoc'
}
```